# Difference between cast and as inside a select in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

This code throws exception:

```
var query = services
             .SomeQuery(bar).select(x => (Foo)x)
             .Where(x.PropertyOfFoo == FooState.SomeState);
var result = query.ToList();
```

The exception:

```
Unable to cast the type...
LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.
```

This code works:

```
var query = services
             .SomeQuery(bar).select(x => x as Foo)
             .Where(x.PropertyOfFoo == FooState.SomeState);
var result = query.ToList();
```

Why does `as` allow the conversion and `cast` does not?

I understand that `as` will return null and cast would throw an exception if either call fails. Okay. But when I run this code:

```
var query = services
             .SomeQuery(bar);
var result = query.ToList();
```

I get a much larger query result. Why?

Comment: It's returning a larger query result because there's no `Where` clause?

Comment: What is `Foo`? A struct?

Comment: What type does `SomeQuery` return?  How is it related to `Foo`?

Comment: `Foo` inherits from `Bar` and it returns `IQueryable<Bar>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

LINQ to Entities is not the same as LINQ to Objects. While [LINQ to Objects functions can take any matching delegate](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,5c652c53e80df013,references) and blindly invoke it as normal C# code, [LINQ to Entities treats your lambdas as expression trees](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/IQueryable.cs,017f3b205593b416) because it needs to understand the semantics of those lambdas (not just their signature) and transform them to an equivalent query for your EF backend. Naturally, this means that LINQ to Entities can't handle all operations that LINQ to Objects can.

Now, as you have said, one difference between casting and using `as` is that casting throws an exception on failure and `as` returns `null`. But there is an even more important difference between the two: [a cast will apply any potential custom explicit conversions, while `as` will simply attempt to reinterpret the reference as something else, ignoring any potential conversions.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/10/08/what-s-the-difference-between-as-and-cast-operators.aspx)

As you understand, a cast is much more complicated than `as`, because a cast may invoke a custom method (the `explicit operator`) that's not easily resolvable by the LINQ provider. It's likely that the provider is simply unable to examine the code of the potential custom conversion (I don't know enough about the limitations of expression trees), let alone translate it for the underlying source. Thus, LINQ to Entities chooses to allow only `as` and the simplest cast cases (basically, it allows the cases where the conversion logic was known ahead of time and can't possibly be custom user code).

Answer (score 3):

There's an important difference between the two statements that shows that more than anything (like CLR rules) Entity Framework is deeply involved here.

1. `x as Foo` is translated into SQL. EF can do that because it knows it will always return a result, either a `Foo` or null. The generated SQL is monstrous by the way, but it does the job.
2. `(Foo)x` is *not* translated into SQL. EF knows that there is no way to create `Foo` objects for *all* `x`'s, as cast semantics demand, and it throws an exception.

Note that EF will accept `foos.Select(f => (Bar)f)`, because it's always possible to create a base type from a subtype. The actual cast is done after the SQL result is received, it doesn't affect the SQL itself.

It will also accept `bars.OfType<Foo>().Select(x => (Foo)x)` (althought this is fairly useless).

So the error message...

> LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.

...isn't entirely true. EF does accept casts when they're doable. So inside EF's query translator there's just a bunch of logic to decide whether or not it's worth the effort to generate a SQL statement.

Comment: +1, nice to know that it supports the simple upcast. I guess the error message is misleading precisely because (as Eric Lippert puts it), the cast operator attempts to mean two essentially contradictory things. It seems like the author of this error message had only one of the two in mind at that moment.

Answer (score 1):

It's a difference in how direct cast works vs. how the `as` operator works.  Direct cast isn't available because you aren't using a value type - it only works for primitives.

Now, your lambda is trying to both select and project - you *could* break that into two operations, so:

```
var result = services.SomeQuery(bar).select(x => new Foo() {
    SomeProperty = x.SomeProperty,
    SomeOtherProperty = x.SomeOtherProperty,
    ... }).ToList()
```

As to the greater number of results: you're missing a `where` clause in there.